# stdcall asm floating point parameters

Tags: assembly, x86, d

using D inline assembly im trying to implement calling stdcall functions dynamically (with dynamic parameters)

i have the following assembly
args is a void pointer to an array of 32bit integers argc is the number of is the argument count ret is a void pointer and address is the function address

```
 MOV EBX, 0;
 iterator:
 MOV EAX, DWORD PTR [args];
 PUSH EAX;
 ADD EBX, 1;
 ADD EAX, 4;
 CMP EBX, DWORD PTR argc;
 JNE iterator;
 MOV EAX, ADDress;
 CALL EAX;
 MOV [ret], EAX;
 RET 0;
```

how are floating point arguments passed?

Comment: On the stack, as everything else. PS: you don't need to load the pointer into `EAX`, you can do `call dword ptr [Address]`. Also note that if you use `push` you need to reverse argument order.

Comment: Calling convention usually depends on language, architecture, and operating system. On x86 floating point values are pushed on the floating point stack.

Comment: @qznc, nope not even close.

Comment: @qznc did you hear about SIMD? On x86_64 the floating-point stack has been deprecated and you use it at your own risk of inconsistency (if you don't know what's going on) and slowness

Comment: You are correct, because we are talking about different architectures. x86 != x86_64. Sidenote, you are most certainly talking "amd64", not "x86_64" which is the (mostly dead) Itanium architecture.

Comment: @qznc: Itanium is ia-64.  x86-64 is amd64.  Also, no 32-bit x86 calling convention I'm aware of passes FP args on the x87 stack.  They're usually passed in memory on the call stack (like in Johan's answer), or in SSE XMM registers (for 32-bit `__vectorcall` I think).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft is very silent on this issue.
This is because `stdcall` is only used for WinAPI calls.
And no WinAPI call that I know of accepts floating point parameters.

[According](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/984x0h58.aspx) to [all](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/el/SSQ2R2_8.5.1/com.ibm.etools.pl1.win.doc/topics/xf6700.htm) the [documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#stdcall) I can find all parameters are pushed onto the stack.
This includes floating point parameters.

If I compile the following snippet in my compiler it confirms this:

```
void __stdcall test3(double a, double b, double c) {
};     
.....
test3(a,b,c);
.....
//This produces the following code as per the stdcall convention. 
004182B4 55               push ebp
004182B5 8BEC             mov ebp,esp
004182B7 83C4E8           add esp,-$18
004182BA FF75EC           push dword ptr [ebp-$14]
004182BD FF75E8           push dword ptr [ebp-$18]
004182C0 FF75F4           push dword ptr [ebp-$0c]
004182C3 FF75F0           push dword ptr [ebp-$10]
004182C6 FF75FC           push dword ptr [ebp-$04]
004182C9 FF75F8           push dword ptr [ebp-$08]
004182CC E8ABFFFFFF       call Test3
```

Note that a floating point return value gets returned in `ST(0)`.